# python problem - running sql query from list

Tags: python, list, teradata

I am trying to read queries in Excel to a Python list, which I was able to achieve.
As a next step, I want to execute all the queries from the list in Teradata (can be any database)
I am getting an error, below is the sample code. Any help is appreciated.

#Working Code:#
            import teradata
            import xlrd
            udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="Hello World", ersion="1.0",  logConsole=False)

```
        session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="tddev",
                username="abc", password="abc!1",authentication="LDAP",driver="Teradata");
                loc = ("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Queries.xlsx")
                wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
        wbsheet=wb.sheet_by_name("Queries")
        total_rows=wbsheet.nrows
        query_list=[]

        for row1 in range(1,total_rows):
            exceldata = wbsheet.row(row1) 
            query_list.append(exceldata)


    # getting an error after adding session execute code to above code # 

        for row2 in query_list:
                session.execute(row2)


Error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/prasnaya/Desktop/Terada_worksheet.py", line 31, in <module>
        session.execute(row2)
      File "C:\Users\prasnaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\teradata\udaexec.py", line 675, in execute
        self.internalCursor.execute(query, params, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\prasnaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\teradata\udaexec.py", line 748, in execute
        self._execute(self.cursor.execute, q, params, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\prasnaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\teradata\udaexec.py", line 790, in _execute
        func(query, params, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\prasnaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\teradata\tdodbc.py", line 613, in execute
        self.hStmt, _inputStr(_convertLineFeeds(query)), SQL_NTS)
      File "C:\Users\prasnaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\teradata\tdodbc.py", line 881, in _convertLineFeeds
        return "\r".join(util.linesplit(query))
      File "C:\Users\prasnaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\teradata\util.py", line 357, in linesplit
        sql if isString(sql) else newline.join(sql))
    TypeError: can only join an iterable


Final Working Code :


import Teradata
import xlrd

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0",
        logConsole=False)

session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="tdprod",
        username="xyz", password="abc!1",authentication="LDAP",
                          driver="Teradata");



loc = ("C:\\Users\\prasnaya\\Desktop\\Queries.xlsx")


wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
wbsheet=wb.sheet_by_name("Queries")
total_rows=wbsheet.nrows


print(total_rows)

query_list=[]




for row1 in range(0,total_rows):
    exceldata = wbsheet.cell_value(row1,0) 
    query_list.append(exceldata)



print(len(query_list))    
for row2 in query_list:
    print(row2)

    for row in session.execute(row2):             
        print(row)    
session.close()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community! What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks, Per for extending help, please find error :   I think it is aborting because  "text:" & '/n" is getting appended to sql query
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\teradata\udaexec.py", line 790, in _execute
    func(query, params, **kwargs)
TypeError: can only join an iterable

Comment: Thanks. I suggest: edit your question to include the full version of the program that worked (i.e. just executed a fixed SQL query towards Excel), then add the full exception details to the end (after the version of the program that _didn't_ work). That way, it will be easier to analyze this and hopefully help you find a solution.

Comment: I have provided the working code & code which was causing error after being added to program

Comment: Thanks! Getting better and better all the time. :) Now, could you add the full stack trace (all the lines) also right, after the second code example?

Comment: haha , I will take that as positive feedback, please find Traceback added ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Teradata
import xlrd

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0",
        logConsole=False)

session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="tdprod",
        username="abc", password="xyz!1",authentication="LDAP",
                          driver="Teradata");



loc = ("C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\Queries.xlsx")


wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
wbsheet=wb.sheet_by_name("Queries")
total_rows=wbsheet.nrows


print(total_rows)

query_list=[]




for row1 in range(0,total_rows):
    exceldata = wbsheet.cell_value(row1,0) 
    query_list.append(exceldata)



print(len(query_list))    
for row2 in query_list:
    print(row2)

    for row in session.execute(row2):             
        print(row)    
session.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is that the linesplit method here (inside teradata) presumes that the `sql` parameter is an iterable:

```
File "C:\Users\prasnaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\teradata\util.py", line 357, in linesplit
  sql if isString(sql) else newline.join(sql))
```

...which it isn't, in your case. Interestingly enough, a Python `str` object *is iterable*. In other words, the query you are getting from your source object (the Excel sheet) is not a proper string.

Possible reasons:

1. Could it be that `row` is a `list`, where each item in the list is a cell from the row? If so, try `row[0]`, or perhaps `str(row[0])` if the former doesn't work.
2. Could it be that it needs a type conversion to string? If so, try `str(row)` (this is unlikely to work but you can always try)
3. Could it be some other type? Please try `print(type(row))`; this should give you the type of the object you are working on to your `stdout`, which might help you better understand the problem here.

Good luck, and please post back your results here so that the question can hopefully help others who run into similar problems.

Comment: Thanks, Per, I will try on your recommended approach and for sure share the result

Comment: Hi Per, finally the query is running and as expected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great to hear! If there is more info to add here that could help others debugging similar issues, please do it. Also, feel free to upvote/mark my answer as correct if you like. :)